# How to convert a list of VMDK files into a qcow2 or img file which have the same size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I've just configured the passthrough on my ubuntu / I9 9900k / nvidia geforce RTX 2080 ti machine. Now I'm converting the VMware virtual machine VMDK files (created from the conversion of a physical installation of Windows 10) into one big qcow2 file with the following command :

```
mario@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/media/ziomario/DATI/DiscoC/DESKTOP-N9UN2H3# qemu-img convert -f vmdk DESKTOP-N9UN2H3*.vmdk -O qcow2 /media/ziomario/WIN/DiscoC/DESKTOP-N9UN2H3/QCOW2/DESKTOP-N9UN2H3.qcow2
```

The physical installation of Windows 10 has a size of 300 GB. The VMDK files produced by the conversion did with vCenter Converter have a size of 558 GB. I don't know what could be the final size of the converted qcow2 file. What I know is that I tried to save it in a disk of 1 TB and it became full. I would like to know if there is a way to convert more than one VMDK file into a qcow2 or img file (these are the formats accepted by qemu/kvm virt-manager) that will have almost the same size of the original ones. thanks.

Comment: does qemu no longer support vmdk images directly?

Comment: I don't see this format in the virt-manager...

Comment: `qemu-img` and `qemu` are built off the same code base. `qemu` with vmdk images did work for me in the past. I don't like `virt-manager` and only used it when having to fix other people's issues.

Answer (score 0):

Virt-manager has a nice GUI, but as said in the comment above they have also some odd idiot ball here and there (possibly due to their RHEL-centrism, which is why vmdk isn't an option [anymore](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/commit/da00a52159635df5f3f209c3ee0aa9d7ee49417f) despite the backend supporting it).

So, assuming the point of your question was getting the "VMDK content" to work with it, I'm going to answer you that you don't need a conversion at all. And contrarily to much [outdated](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/f66fd6c383edc137fa618c250ea40c1936a52f1c) info in the web, split and sparse images are supported too.

You just need to open the Host Storage dialog (either at VM creation time by selecting *import existing disk image*, or from the storage options of an existing VM), then add your VMDK like you would do normally.

It will be autodetected as a raw file disk, which you will need [to adjust](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=801813) in the XML with: `<driver name="qemu" type="vmdk"/>`. And profit.